# An alien comes to Earth and says $7\times7=41$. How many fingers does he have?

Tags: puzzle

I understand this sounds ridiculous at first but I got asked this question by a supply teacher $3$ days ago and I haven't been able to answer it so it's driving me insane.

I got given two hints:

- It's over $10$ fingers
- because we have $10$ fingers we count in base $10$ which is why for us $7\times7=49$

Comment: [Puzzling Stack Exchange](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Consider that 41 in base 12 is 49 in base 10.

Comment: Hint: Start by cutting off the extra finger.

Comment: I didn't know [the Babylonians had 60 fingers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylonian_numerals)

Comment: This is not what you should do if an alien comes to Earth.

Answer (score 9):

The question is equivalent to $ 7 \times 7 = 4 \times n + 1 $, and solve for $n$ (the number of fingers). Hence $n = 12$.

Comment: why do we have $4 \times n + 1$?

Comment: @LeeKM: because that's how place value works in base $n$.

Answer (score 7):

7x7 = 49 in base 10. If the alien says it's 41, it's base is higher. If we try with base 12

$$ 49 / 12 = 4 \land 49 \% 12 = 1 \implies 49_{10} = 41_{12} $$

But how many hands does it has? One? two? ten? Are they evenly distributed? Let's just assume they are humanoid, so two hands, therefore six fingers per hand?